# Monitor incoming emails in app for Office 2013 using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, office-2013, outlook-web-app

I am looking to monitor all new incoming emails in **Outlook Online (Outlook web App)** using **JavaScript API for Office** and get the email's details like sender, subject etc.. Basically I need to send an auto reply to sender with tracking number attached to subject.

I tried to use **Office.context.mailbox** object, but it didn't work for me. I need to execute my app every time whenever there is a new email in my mailbox.

Any Ideas or suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS API for Office doesn't provide anything for that. You may try to use [Outlook Notifications REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations). Or develop a COM add-in (VSTO) or VBA macro where you can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class. See [Selecting an API or Technology for Developing Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg608200(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene for your support.